# scroll page selenium webdriver JS

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to test on selenium webdriver JS. I have functions that look for an element on the site.

```
 createAccount() {
        return this.driver.findElement(By.css(".button"));
    }
```

There is a function that scrolls the page to the desired item. I want to scroll through the function, pass the search function as an argument.

```
scrollToElement(el) {
        this.driver.manage().window().maximize();
         return  this.driver.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', el );
    }
```

The test runs in a separate file.

```
 async main() {
    const page = this.Page;
    page.open();
    page.scrollToElement(createAccount);
    await page.createAccount().click();
}
```

And when I run it, an error appears:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: JavascriptError: javascript error: Cannot read property 'scrollToElement' of null

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it cannot find the `createAccount` element.
Try finding the element using the `id` or by `xpath`.